# New Ubuntu Server best practice for setup

Tags: ubuntu, security

When setting up droplets on Digital Ocean it is encouraged to setup some basic security and monitoring. I have read around quite a lot recently on best practices for hardening a new Ubuntu server. Below are the steps I have compiled. Does the community have any suggestions for tweaks to this list including additions or removals?

1. Create a non-root user [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server), [8](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/)]
2. Add non-root to the sudoers group [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [8](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/)]
3. Add public ssh key to non-root user [[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-security-measures-to-protect-your-servers), [2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [8](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/)]
4. Deny all inbound traffic with ufw firewall [[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-security-measures-to-protect-your-servers), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [4](https://github.com/MartynKeigher/ghost-on-digitalocean-512MB), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server)]
5. Open required ports within the ufw firewall [[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-security-measures-to-protect-your-servers), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [4](https://github.com/MartynKeigher/ghost-on-digitalocean-512MB), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server)]
6. Update SSH config - Password-less logins [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server), [8](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/), [9](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/221494788-Best-practices-for-SSH-configuration)]
7. Update SSH config - Disable root login [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [5](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server), [8](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/), [9](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/221494788-Best-practices-for-SSH-configuration)]
8. Update SSH config - Change ssh port [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server), [8](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/), [9](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/221494788-Best-practices-for-SSH-configuration)]
9. Unattented upgrades [[3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [4](https://github.com/MartynKeigher/ghost-on-digitalocean-512MB), [6](http://www.zartl.info/?p=422), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server)]
10. Postfix for emails [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [6](http://www.zartl.info/?p=422)]
11. Logswatch to send daily summary emails [[3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/)]
12. Fail2ban [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server), [3](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/), [7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server)]
13. Set the timezone to UTC and install NTP [[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server)]
14. Secure shared memory [[5](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/)]
15. Add a security login banner [[[5](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/)]
16. Harden the networking layer [[5](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/)]
17. Prevent IP spoofing [[5](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/)]

**Sources**

[1. Digital Ocean - 7 Security Measures to Protect your Servers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-security-measures-to-protect-your-servers)

[2. Digital Ocean - What do you do with your first five minutes on a new server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-do-you-do-with-your-first-five-minutes-on-a-new-server)

[3. Securing a Server with Ansible](https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/securing-a-server-with-ansible/)

[4. Ghost on Digitalocean 512MB](https://github.com/MartynKeigher/ghost-on-digitalocean-512MB)

[5. Tech Republic - How to harden ubuntu server 16-04 security in five step](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-harden-ubuntu-server-16-04-security-in-five-steps/)

[6. How to configure Auto-Updates on Linux Ubuntu Servers](http://www.zartl.info/?p=422)

[7. Linode - Securing your Server](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server)

[8. Rackspace - Linux Server Security Best Practices](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/linux-server-security-best-practices/)

[9. Best practices for SSH configuration](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/221494788-Best-practices-for-SSH-configuration)

If this is not the best place to ask this, where is?

Comment: With sources this many you could almost write a scientific paper about the issue. Most would only follow one tutorial, but you are actually collecting information to understand what's important and what else can be done. The question being too broad here doesn't mean it's bad or doesn't show any effort. Good job!